# Create and show Toasts/Snackbars from within AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-snackbar

I have a recyclerlistview that is populated using inputs gathered from an AlertDialog, which is spawned from a floating action button. When the positive button in the AlertDialog is pressed and all inputs are formatted correctly the SQLite db gets updated and after that the snackbar is made and shown from within the same listener.

- If the input is malformatted, then toast is displayed, but also the dialog closes which i do not want
- If the input is correct the dialog closes and the data gets added to the list, but the SnackBar is not showing

This is the onClickListener in my MainActivity:

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View view) 
 {
switch ( view.getId() )

    {

        case R.id.add_item_btn:

        View addDialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_dialog, null);
        final EditText addItemNameTxt  = addDialogView.findViewById(R.id.add_item_name_txt);
        final EditText addItemCountTxt = addDialogView.findViewById(R.id.add_item_count_txt);

        // something unimportant left out

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(addDialogView)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i)
            {
                if ( addItemNameTxt.getText().length() == 0 )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                String itemName = addItemNameTxt.getText().toString();
                String itemCount = addItemCountTxt.getText().toString();

                dbHelper.insertTask(itemName, Integer.parseInt(itemCount));
                taskAdapter.swapCursor(dbHelper.getTasks());

                dialog.dismiss();

                Snackbar.make(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null).findViewById(R.id.rootLayout), String.format("Added \"%s (%s)\" to list", itemName, itemCount), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        })
        .create().show();

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe create viewgroup that mimick your dialog and just do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works (= not closing for toasting + snacking upon successful exit) when a button is put into the custom layout and that one is used instead of AlertDialog.PositiveButton.

```
            final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(addDialogView)
            .create();

            addDialogView.findViewById(R.id.add_confirm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view2) {
                    if ( addItemNameTxt.getText().length() == 0 )
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    String itemName = addItemNameTxt.getText().toString();
                    String itemCount = addItemCountTxt.getText().toString();

                    dbHelper.insertTask(itemName, Integer.parseInt(itemCount));
                    taskAdapter.swapCursor(dbHelper.getTasks());

                    Snackbar.make(view, String.format("Added \"%s (%s)\" to list", itemName, itemCount), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
```